# When Clicking on Navigation Buttons, Save Form data to Grid and Server

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid, the edit form can be configured to [display or hide the previous and next navigation buttons][1].

I want to save the Form data to the Grid and Server when the user clicks on the navigation buttons.

I am going to try this:

```
jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid('FormToGrid',rowid);

jQuery("#list_klanten").saveRow(rowid);
```

Comment: What you mean under "the javascript to save the form"? Do you want to save the position of the form? Do you want to suppress going to the next/previous row inside of `onclickPgButtons` callback? I the case you need just return `false` from `onclickPgButtons` callback.

Comment: If user clicks on navigation button, then save form data to server and update display of data in the grid.

Comment: Do you tried to trigger `click` on Submit button inside of `onclickPgButtons`? You can do just `$("#sData").click()`. If you don't use `closeAfterEdit: true` or `closeAfterAdd: true` it should work.